# Foliage Plant identification and help with yellow spotting on leaves

Tags: identification, diseases

Can you please help me with two (related) things? Firstly, can anyone tell me what the non-ivy plant in the picture is? I got it at a local supermarket for Christmas a couple of years back, and it just said 'Christmas basket' with no description of the contents.

[image: overall picture of plant in basket]

Secondly, can someone help me with diagnosing the leaf spotting?
[image: close-up of leaf problem]

It has been sitting over the kitchen hob for the better part of the last two years, and when it initially appeared a couple of months back, I assumed it was just steam/hot oil spraying onto and damaging the leaves. However, it's spreading to leaves which are not close to the hob, and it really looks more like a disease than mechanical damage. I'd google it, if I knew the name of the plant... hence the double question!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a Parlor palm (Chamaedorea elegans). It is commonly used in house plant arrangements. I have attached a link below.  It is hard to tell what may be ailing the leaf in the photo. It could be heat or sun stress. The leaf may just be growing old and beginning to show signs of dying. If the younger leaves show no sign of distress, then it may be nothing to worry about. Hopefully the link below might have more information.

http://www.palmpedia.net/wiki/Chamaedorea_elegans

Comment: Thanks! Actually we have been having unusually hot and sunny days lately, so that might be it. Also, I'm planning on changing the soil, as it's still in the same one from two Christmases ago...